# Jensen inequality for convex functions - infinite countable number of weights

Tags: measure-theory, inequality, convex-analysis

Does Jensen inequality for convex functions hold if there is countable infinite number of weights? For example weights are given by sequence $(\frac{1}{2^n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}_1}$ ?

If not, where is the problem?

Comment: I think it still holds.

Comment: are you sure?  It's improtant to me. Why  it's not stated like that if it holds?

Comment: "Why it's not stated like that if it holds?" [Is it not?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). See end of "Proof 1", inter alia.

Comment: In general, if $A$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and $f(x)$ a convex function over $x \in A$, then, if $X$ is a random variable that takes values in $A$, and if $E[X]$ is finite, then $E[X] \in A$ and $f(E[X]) \leq E[f(X)]$.  So, in your case of a countably infinite number of possibilities, you just have to take care that $E[X]$ is finite.  For example, let $x_n=4^n$ and let $X$ be a random variable that is $x_n$ with probaiblity $1/2^n$.  Then $E[X]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}4^n = \infty$ and so $f(E[X])$ is not really defined.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ is convex (and continuous).

Let's prove That for $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ bounded and $w_1, w_2, \ldots$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} w_i=1$, $f(w_1x_1+w_2x_2+\cdots) \leq w_1f(x_1)+w_2f(x_2)+\cdots$

Given $\epsilon>0$, we can choose $N$ sufficiently large that $|f(w_1x_1+\cdots)-f(w_1x_1+\cdots+w_Nx_N)|<\epsilon$ and $|\sum_{i=N+1}^\infty w_if(x_i)|<\epsilon$. Thus, $f(w_1x_1+\cdots)<f(w_1x_1+\cdots+w_Nx_N)+\epsilon \leq w_1f(x_1)+\cdots+w_Nf(x_N)+\epsilon <2\epsilon + w_1f(x_1)+w_2f(x_2)+\cdots$

(In the second inequality, we have used Jensen's inequality of finite case)

Because $\epsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small, we have $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} w_i=1$, $f(w_1x_1+w_2x_2+\cdots) \leq w_1f(x_1)+w_2f(x_2)+\cdots$.